# Write an item to a tkinter listbox from a function outside

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I run a small chatserver, where people can connect and chat with eachother. I want to use a tkinter listbox to monitor the incoming connections.

This is my GUI after starting the server script.

[image]

After a user connected to the server, a message like "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX has connected appears on my listbox:

[image]

I do not know why the listbox duplicated on that point.

Attached the code:

```
def accept_incoming_connections():
"""Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
       client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
       s = str("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
       client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave!" + "Now type your name and press enter!", "utf8"))
       addresses[client] = client_address
       print(s)
       App().insert_log(s)
       Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()


class App(tkinter.Tk):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text="", width=20, anchor="w")
       self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
       self.title('Chat - Server')
       self.geometry('400x400')
       self.messages_frame = tkinter.Frame()
       self.messages_frame.pack()
       self.msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(self.messages_frame, height=15, width=50)
       self.msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, 'Server ONLINE!')
       self.msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, 'AP: ' + str(ap))
       self.msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, 'IP: ' + str(ip))
       self.msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, 'Port: ' + str(PORT))
       self.msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, 'Waiting for connections..')
       self.msg_list.pack()

    def insert_log(self, logtext):
       self.msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, logtext)


def create_gui():
   app = App()
   app.mainloop()


def main():
   SERVER.listen(5)  # Listens for 5 connections at max.
   ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
   ACCEPT_THREAD.start()  # Starts the infinite loop
   GUI = Thread(target=create_gui)
   GUI.start()  # Starts the gui
   print('Server running. Waiting for clients...')
   ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
   SERVER.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

The listbox item is created on def accept_incoming_connections(): -> App().insert_log(s)

Where is the duplication coming from?

Comment: using `App().insert_log(s)` in loop you create window many times and it can add second listbox to window. Probably it will create more listboxes when you will have more clients. You should creat `App()` only once - but it means once not only in `accept_incoming_connections` but once in all threads. Better create `App` only in `create_gui`. And create `queue` which you use in both threads to send messages from second thread to first thread with GUI and first thread should  add it to lixtbox.

Comment: I agree with furas, you should create the gui and then run a class ThreadedTask  with the threading.Thread module with a queue. Otherwise threading doesn't work well with tkinter.